# How to search strings within an array that has values containing two or more words (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contains some elements with two words, for example array("Dark Blue", "Carnation Pink").. What function do I need to use to search an array value that contains a specified string to be search. If I searched "Dark", the value "Dark Blue" should show.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

```
$found = preg_grep('/\bDark\b/', $arr);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4i0PLo).

You could also use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a regex..

```
$found = array_filter($arr, function($value) {
  return preg_match('/\bDark\b/', $value);
});
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fGuXoW).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good old fashioned foreach loop?

```
$search_for = "Dark";

foreach (array("Dark Blue", "Carnation Pink") as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, $search_for) !== false) {
        echo "Found $value<br/>";
    }
}
```